# Weird line in my mirrored mesh

Tags: modeling

was following a tutorial where I stumbled into this weird line in my mirrored mesh (sorry for the feet lol)

[image]

[image]

You can also download the blender file
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Problem

This is caused by faces inside your mesh. The main sign of this is that the crease only appears when subsurf is turned up; the inside faces add weight that pulls the verticies inwards (according to the subsurf algorithm).

### Solution

*Tab* into edit mode and uncheck the *X* box in the *Mirror modifier*. Your properties panel should look like this:

[image]

This will leave you with half a human. Change into face select mode: [image] and select these faces:

[image]

Key *X* and select *Faces*. Tab out of edit mode and recheck *X* in the *Mirror modifier*. This is the repaired mesh:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, And I just increased the merge limit in the mirror modifier, and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after applying the mirror modifier (no crease but a sharp line between mirrors). What worked for me was to select all and use *Mesh - Normals - Set from faces* in edit mode after the modifier was applied.