# How to straighten distorted edge

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I'm using the subdivision surface modifier and noticed that on section of my mesh, the edges are very distorted. I've tried scaling along an axis, editing when subdivision modifier is off, tried pulling vertices to try and line them up properly but can't seem to get it. Lines look normal when I turn modifier off. (See 2nd image in object mode)

Sculpt mode seems to jack it up even more. But perhaps I'm not using the correct tool.

Any suggestions on how to straighten or smooth the edges so that the mesh is smoother?

[image: Edges and vertices are distorted with subdivision surface modifier on]

[image: Object mode of offending edges]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird line in my mirrored mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

So I may have fixed my own problem. It seems that there was a duplicate edge in there that was causing it. Removed and recreated the faces and that seems to have fixed my issue.