# sharp creases on the edges between the mirror and the model

Tags: mirror

for some reason i keep getting this raised surface in the middle of the face of my model. i checked the order of my modifiers and i tried smoothing it out, adding more edgeloops but that creates its own set of problems i found out. what i have been doing is manually adjusting each vertex but its a tedious task and feels very inefficient. also i don't want to have to do this for every organic model i create with the mirror modifier. also, i'm not sure if this is due to the mirror mod or the subsurf mod or if it's just me not placing the vertices in the correct spots.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird line in my mirrored mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right/

Comment: Looks like it's just a problem of adjusting the position of the vertices to me, did you by any chance modify the crease value of those edges? you can find it in the transform panel on the right under "edge data" when you are in edit mode, make sure it's set to zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.  i haven't modified any values aside from moving the vertices to create the facial topology. in fact i never even noticed the crease values below the transform values. I keep thinking that it might be related to how I'm placing the vertices on the face. but I don't know for sure. i wish I could uppload the file so you guys can take a look for me.

Comment: Then I guess it's just a problem with how youplaced the vertices, I know it's a long and boring task but try to adjust them by hand and see what comes out.

Comment: Apply the subsurface modifier after the mirror modifier.

Comment: I think it would be handy to see a wireframe of the model as well?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a face inside the mesh, right where it gets mirrored. That often causes some weird stuff to happen if you add another modifier