# About anvil modelling problem caused by mirror modifier

Tags: modeling

In this model, I have used extrude, loop cut, inset for creating the model and the modifiers that I used was boolean, mirror modifier along the y axis and the subsurf modifier. The problem is why there seems to be a line between the mirror and the object where I lined  it blue? Is there anyway to solve this ? At first, I think maybe there is a face between the model and the mirror but I have deleted it so I think the problem lies somewhere else.

I have made the vertices along the center and scale their 'y' location to 0. 
And I have found some problem that some parts of the  meshes would go beyond the center even if I have already clipping turned on. I cannot find any face that is between the mirror and the model so I don't think that is the problem and I also have removed the doubles

my blender file
[image]

[image: part of the meshes go beyond clipping]
[image: example of the affected mesh]
[image: unaffected part]

[image: the anvil model]

[image: the wireframe mode of the model]

[image: blue-lined model]

Comment: Do you have 'merge' and 'clipping' options enabled in your mirror modifier?

Comment: @ajwood  I have enabled both 'merge' and 'clipping' in my mirror modifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Weird line in my mirrored mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh)

Comment: @arcv some parts of you second screenshot are surprising given that you have clipping enabled (e.g., the bottom-most vertex along the centre line is farther left than I would have thought possible). Try selecting all of the vertices along the center and scale their 'y' location to zero (sy0). Then set the object origin to (average location of the) select vertices.

Comment: @ajwood I have found something that is strange and updated my question, what causes this?

Comment: I think some of your vertices got past the clipping point before you enabled clipping. Now that you have clipping on, with the edge loop selected, grab/move them all back toward the correct side of the model. They should get "stuck" when they arrive at the axis of symmetry.

Comment: @ajwood tried but doesn't work. It seems like the edge loop that has problems is the one near the mirror , other edge loop doesn't seem to have this problem since when I move them near the mirror, the clipping works just fine. I have also uploaded my blender file

Comment: In you attached .blend file, with the vertices you already have selected, go to right ortho view (numpad 3), and click+drag the green 'Y' handle to the left.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer to the problem.  First, grab the center loop and move it towards the center till the clipping does not allow it to go any further.  This makes sure that all of the vertices on the center loop are at the center of the model.  Next, you must move the mirror modifier up above the subdivision surface modifier.  This is a general rule of thumb that will remove the seam problem.
Glad to be of help!